# Transition matrix of polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Good night, i need help with this.

Find the transition matrix that goes from the basis W to the basis $\left\{ 2,1-2x,x^{2}-1,x^{3}-x^{2}+x\right\} $

I found a basis for W, $\left\{ 2,x,x^{2}+1,x^{3}\right\} $ and i work in a linear combination of basis W to V and i make a system, but then I had problems with the system

$\begin{cases}
2=\alpha_{1}\left(2\right)+\alpha_{2}\left(1-2x\right)+\alpha_{3}\left(x^{2}-1\right)+\alpha_{4}\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+x\right)\\
x=\alpha_{1}\left(2\right)+\alpha_{2}\left(1-2x\right)+\alpha_{3}\left(x^{2}-1\right)+\alpha_{4}\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+x\right)\\
x^{2}+1=\alpha_{1}\left(2\right)+\alpha_{2}\left(1-2x\right)+\alpha_{3}\left(x^{2}-1\right)+\alpha_{4}\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+x\right)\\
x^{3}=\alpha_{1}\left(2\right)+\alpha_{2}\left(1-2x\right)+\alpha_{3}\left(x^{2}-1\right)+\alpha_{4}\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+x\right)
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do now is to organize the four sets of the four $\alpha$'s that you will find from your four **systems** of equations (do you see why each identity you wrote is a **system** of equations?) into a $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$.

Finally, whether it's $A$, $A^T$, $A^{-1}$, or $(A^T)^{-1}$ that is the answer you're looking for depends on your definition of transition matrix.

Comment: okay, but i have an dude because i don't know how is the 4x4 matrix, because scalar confuse me. @Lem.ma

Comment: i work in a matrix, $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1-2x & x^{2}-1 & x^{3}-x^{2}+x & =2\\
2 & 1-2x & x^{2}-1 & x^{3}-x^{2}+x & =x\\
2 & 1-2x & x^{2}-1 & x^{3}-x^{2}+x & =x^{2}\\
2 & 1-2x & x^{2}-1 & x^{3}-x^{2}+x & =x^{3}
\end{bmatrix}
 $